# Expo: Notification registration failed: "Push Notifications" capability hasn't been added to the app in current environment

Tags: reactjs, react-native, push-notification, expo

```
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import * as Notifications from 'expo-notifications';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import * as Sentry from 'sentry-expo';

export const tokenFunction = async (clientID: string | number | null) => {
    try {
        if (Constants.isDevice) {
            const { status: existingStatus } = await Notifications.getPermissionsAsync();
            let finalStatus = existingStatus;
            if (existingStatus !== 'granted') {
                const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();
                finalStatus = status;
            }
            if (finalStatus !== 'granted') {
                alert('Failed to get push token for push notification!');
                return;
            }
            const token = (await Notifications.getDevicePushTokenAsync()).data;

        }

        if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
            Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync('default', {
                name: 'default',
                importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
                vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
                lightColor: '#FF231F7C',
            });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};
```

await Notifications.getDevicePushTokenAsync() throws errror: Notification registration failed: "Push Notifications" capability hasn't been added to the app in current environment

Comment: This sounds like an iOS-only error.  Did you follow all the steps at [this link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/registering_your_app_with_apns)?